# Edittext does not show keyboard On Click

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a screen with four EditTexts, any edittext doesn't open the keyboard when I click on it. I'm not using an AVD, I'm using my own device, and tested in others devices and same result.My app has some activities like Login , sigup, home activity. In login and sigup activity edittext works correctly but in fragments of home activity keyboard is not opening.

**XML**
```

````
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="100dp">

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:background="@color/global_bg"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/profile"
                app:civ_border_color="@color/main_color"
                app:civ_border_width="5dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fullname_field"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/bungee"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:text="Muneeb Ur Rehman"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="19sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/city_field_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:text="user_city"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-80dp"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/main_color"
            app:cardElevation="10dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/total_orders"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totalOrders"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/bungee"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:text="12"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total_orders_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/totalOrders"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:text="Total Orders"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/main_color"
            app:cardElevation="10dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/pending_orders"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pendingOrders"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/bungee"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pendingOrders_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/pendingOrders"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:text="Pending Orders"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="19dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_edittext_shape"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:padding="13dp"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color_edittext" />


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/user_mobile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_edittext_shape"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_phone_iphone_24"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:hint="Mobile Number"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:padding="13dp"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color_edittext" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/user_city"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_edittext_shape"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_location_city_24"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:hint="City"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="13dp"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color_edittext" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/user_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_edittext_shape"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_location_on_24"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:hint="Address"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="13dp"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color_edittext" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnUpdate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_btn"
            android:fontFamily="@font/bungee"
            android:text="UPDATE"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/main_color" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_btn"
            android:fontFamily="@font/bungee"
            android:text="Logout"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/main_color" />

    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>


 </ScrollView>
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try using `editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(true)` and `editText.setFocusable(true)`
Also check your `AndoridManifest.xml` and add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"` to corresponding activity, or `adjustResize`.

```
   <activity
    android:name="com.fortrun.testcrashlytics.MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
   </activity>
```

> "**adjustResize**" The activity's main window is always resized to make
> room for the soft keyboard on screen.
>
> "**stateAlwaysVisible**"  The soft keyboard is visible when the window receives input focus.

Comment: It's still not working

Comment: Check your themes or styles if you have some custom behavior defined for home activity. 
Try using `android:focusable="true"` and  `<requestFocus />` inside your xml